# reledmac + imakeidx: change the suffix appended to the reference number in the index according to the footnote series

Tags: imakeidx, reledmac

I have one apparatus of variants and one of interpolated verses. I need to index words that are in the two apparatuses and I would like the suffix defined by the command `\ledinnotemark` to change accordingly: the default suffix (*n*) should refer to the apparatus of variants and a new suffix (+) should refer to the interpolations.

I tried to use `\renewcommand{\ledinnotemark}[1]{#1+}` inside the `\add` command, which I have defined to manage the interpolations, but nothing happens. Any suggestions?

Here is a MWE:

```
% !TEX encoding = utf8
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{latin}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\usepackage[series={A,B},noend,nofamiliar,noledgroup,nopbinverse]{reledmac}
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\Xnonumber[A]
\Xinplaceoflemmaseparator{0pt}
\Xinplaceofnumber{0pt}

%%%% Remove the page number from the index
\renewcommand{\thepageline}{%
    \xlineref{\edindexlab\thelabidx}%
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thestartpageline}{%
    \l@dparsedstartline%
}
\renewcommand{\theendpageline}{%
    \l@dparsedendline%
}
\makeatother
%%%%

\newcommand{\add}[2]{\edtext{}{\lemma{}\Afootnote[nosep]{#1 \emph{#2}}}}
%\newcommand{\add}[2]{\renewcommand{\ledinnotemark}[1]{##1+}\edtext{}{\lemma{}\Afootnote[nosep]{#1 \emph{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\var}[2]{\edtext{#1}{\Bfootnote{#2}}}
\newcommand{\nom}[2]{#1\edindex[nom]{#2}}

\makeindex[name=nom,title=Index nominum]

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\setstanzaindents{0,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}

    \stanza
    \add{Ille ego, qui quondam gracili modulatus auena}{}%
    \add{Carmen et egressus siluis uicina coegi,}{}%
    \add{Vt quamuis auido parerent arua colono,}{}%
    \add{Gratum opus agricolis, at nunc horrentia \nom{Martis}{Mars}}{— ante v.~\edlineref{arma}}%
    \edlabel{arma}Arma uirumque cano, \nom{Troiae}{Troia} qui primus ab oris&
    \nom{Italiam}{Italia} fato profugus \var{\nom{Lauiniaque}{Lauinium}}{\nom{Lauinaque}{Lauinium}} uenit&
    Litora, multum ille et terris iactatus et alto&
    Vi superum, saeuae memorem Iunonis ob iram,&
    Multa quoque et bello passus, dum conderet urbem&
    Inferretque deos \nom{Latio}{Latium}, genus unde \nom{Latinum}{Latium}&
    \nom{Albanique}{Alba Longa} patres atque altae moenia \nom{Romae}{Roma}.\&

\endnumbering

\printindex[nom]

\end{document}
```

[image: Apparatus]
[image: Index]

I would like the index to read: Mars, 1+

Comment: Thats is not possible, as the ledinnodemark is interpretated when the footnote is typeset, not when the  entries is added to the indexation. What I should do is to provide the possibilibity to customize it by series. That need some devellopement, not very complex. Please open an issue on github.

Comment: Thank you, I did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was not available on the version of reledmac you used.

You have asked me on github, and I have implemented the feature. So this answer is more for other readers.

With reledmac 2.33.0, which will be send ASAP to CTAN, we do not redefine anymore `ledinnotemark` but use instead two hooks `\innotemarkX` (for familiar footnotes) and  `\Xinnotemark` (for critical footnotes).

As all the hook, it can take an optional argument, which is the series, and a mandatory one, which is the setting.

The mandatory argument can use the following things:

- `#1` for the series
- `##1` for the reference.

So an example would be:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{latin}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\usepackage[series={A,B},noledgroup,nopbinverse,noeledsec,noend]{reledmac}

\makeindex[name=nom,title=Index nominum]
\innotemarkX[A]{##1+}
\innotemarkX[B]{##1*}
\Xinnotemark[A]{##1\textsuperscript{+}}
\Xinnotemark[B]{##1\textsuperscript{*}}
\setstanzaindents{0,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
\Xnonumber
\Xinplaceofnumber{0pt}
\begin{document}
    \beginnumbering

    \stanza
    \edtext{}{\Afootnote[nosep]{… Gratum opus agricolis, at nunc horrentia Martis\edindex[nom]{Mars} — ante v.~1}}\footnoteA{… Gratum opus agricolis, at nunc horrentia Martis\edindex[nom]{Mars} — ante v.~1}%
    Arma uirumque cano, Troiae\edindex[nom]{Troia} qui primus ab oris&
    Italiam\edindex[nom]{Italia} fato profugus \edtext{Lauiniaque\edindex[nom]{Lauinium}}{\Bfootnote{Lauinaque\edindex[nom]{Lauinium}}} ueni…\footnoteB{Lauinaque\edindex[nom]{Lauinium}}\&

    \endnumbering

    \printindex[nom]

\end{document}
```